# How do I convert a vector<string> to a const char* const* in c++?

Tags: c++, data-conversion

I am trying to convert data into the right format for a specific unit test.
The task is to mine a set of words, the unit tests will make sure the results are correct. I have no access to the unit tests, just the declaration which takes a  const char* const* Result.

So I need to get my

```
std::vector<string> Words;
```

to

```
const char* const* Result;
```

divided by a non-alpha char (for example space).

I am aware that this is a constant pointer to a constant character, so I am not sure what to do here since they both constant?

Any pointers (word pun not really intended) are appreciated!

Comment: What does "divided by a non-alpha char" mean? The `vector<string>` is already divided into strings.

Comment: The test requires a const char* const* !

Comment: Are you sure about "divided by a non-alpha char"? Normally you don't need any extra division, in addition to null-terminating your strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully convert one to the other. However, you can convert an array of `std::string` into an array of pointers to char, and a pointer to the first element of such array would be compatible with your desired result:

```
std::vector<const char*> Ptrs;
std::transform(
    std::cbegin(Words), std::cend(Words),
    std::back_inserter(Ptrs),
    [](auto& str)  { return str.c_str(); }
);
const char* const* Result = Ptrs.data();
```

Just remember that the strings themselves are still stored in the `std::string` objects and those pointers within the new vector are only valid as long as the strings in the original vector exist, aren't resized, and the original vector itself isn't resized.

And the pointer to first element of the new vector is only valid as long as that vector exists and isn't resized.

Answer (score 6):

Seems easy enough

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

// ...

std::vector<char const*> result_owner(Words.size());
std::transform(begin(Words), end(Words), begin(result_owner), 
               std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str));

const char* const* Result = result_owner.data();
```

Just because `Result` must provide a const view of the buffer, doesn't mean the buffer has to really be const itself. So it's just another vector that we obtain by projecting `Words` on the `std::string::c_str` member.

After that `Result` can simply be another reference to `result_owner.data();`.

This of course assumes that `Result` doesn't have to *own* the buffer it points at. Owning raw pointers are best avoided.

Answer (score 4):

And the caveman way to do it :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char **foo(const vector<string> &vec_of_strings)
{
    int num_strings = vec_of_strings.size();
    int max_str_len = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<num_strings;i++)
    {
        if (max_str_len < vec_of_strings[i].length()) {
            max_str_len = vec_of_strings[i].length();
        }
    }

    // for null termination ...
    max_str_len++;

    char **result = (char **) malloc(num_strings);

    for (int i=0;i<num_strings;i++)
    {
        result[i] = (char *) malloc(max_str_len);
        strcpy(result[i],vec_of_strings[i].c_str());
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<string> vec_of_strings;

    vec_of_strings.push_back("Long");
    vec_of_strings.push_back("Livvvvvvvve");
    vec_of_strings.push_back("The");
    vec_of_strings.push_back("King");

    const char * const * Result = foo(vec_of_strings);

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",Result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a +1 for the sheer audacity :D

Comment: Callers responsibility to do a `free(Result);` when done using Result.

Comment: @Eljay not only `Result` but `Result[i]` for each `i` as well.